# Can SE Search be 'honed'?

Tags: discussion, support

Case in point…
[even if I was looking at a Super User question & the terms I was starting from are very generic, it felt best to ask in Ask Different, as my 'home' community]

[Why does my screensaver say [myname]'s Macbook Pro (4)](https://superuser.com/questions/912499/why-does-my-screensaver-say-mynames-macbook-pro-4)

I was trying to start with a broad search for issues where the Mac name increments by number…

Not being sure where to start I went for `(2)` as a start point, hoping to hone it later…
Unfortunately, results coming in were 'anything including a `2`'

I'm no expert in grep or anything like that, but I'm not bad at honing down Google searches, by keyword, site: etc.

Does SE have any 'honing tools' for this type of broad start point?
Things like AND, OR, "full-string" etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a full guide to searching at [/help/searching](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Exact match searches are accomplished by enclosing the string in `"`. Punctuation is excluded from search strings, even when using exact match.

If all else fails, you can always search using Google with the `site:apple.stackexchange.com` parameter.

Comment: That may have been my issue. I really needed "(2)" as the string, yet it was ignoring punctuation. Google does the same, unfortunately. I think it's just one of those edge-cases where I really would have been better-off following the old farmer's advice when asked directions…"Well, you don't want to start from here." ;)